# Elasticsearch local node has no active shards

Tags: java, elasticsearch, dropwizard

I have a java/dropwizard application using elasticsearch (running version 1.3.2 but I've also tested with 1.4.0)

For local development/testing I use elasticsearch in local mode, starting it with the following commands:

```
Node node = nodeBuilder().local(true).node();
Client client = node.client();
```

According the documentation (http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/client.html, section on Node Client) this should be sufficient, but I'm not able to run any queries. Checking the health status I get the following result:

```
{
    "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
    "status" : "red",
    "timed_out" : false,
    "number_of_nodes" : 1,
    "number_of_data_nodes" : 1,
    "active_primary_shards" : 0,
    "active_shards" : 0,
    "relocating_shards" : 0,
    "initializing_shards" : 0,
    "unassigned_shards" : 10
}
```

I assume the problem is that I have no active shards. Do anyone know how activate shards for this kind of setup?

Comment: Nope. I gave up and installed a local elasticsearch server instead